# Returning to a UIViewController has its view scrolled out

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using iOS 6. I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView`. The `ScrollView` is a login screen i.e. labels, text fields and buttons to login.

In order to scroll to appropriate field when the keyboard pops out, I use following code from Apple developer documentation:

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = self.activeField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [self.activeField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, self.activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
}

- (void)resetUIEdgeInsets
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [self resetUIEdgeInsets];
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self resetUIEdgeInsets];
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}
```

It works fine. The problem occurs when I Modal segue to another view controller, and dismiss back to here. The scroll position SOMETIMES (intermittently) is completely out of space.

Am I doing something wrong up here. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting `[self resetUIEdgeInsets]` in `viewWillAppear`? Since the view controller remains on the stack and won't call `viewDidLoad` after dismissing the modal VC

Comment: @John Just tried you suggestion but no luck. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your scrollView's name to something else. I had the same problem before. There were 2 UIScrollView in the same vc and after modal view presented ana dismissed, one of them was always misplaced.

Comment: thanks @user1111278 ... that didn't work for me. Did changing the name of the UIScrollView outlet work for you? AM I making a mistake somewhere else?